# Как правильно пишется - вместе или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

В слове "несправедлива" НЕ пишется вместе или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы дать точный ответ на вопрос, нужно знать контекст.

Если вы говорите, что *учительница не справедлива, а бесчестна* (о ужас!), то стоит писать *не* раздельно с кратким прилагательным, так как здесь ***не* - отрицательная частица**.

А вот в словосочетаниях типа *жизнь несправедлива*, ***не* - приставка** и пишется слитно.

Помните, что есть краткие формы прилагательных, которые **всегда** пишутся раздельно: *не рад, не должен, не горазд, не склонен, не готов, не прав, не намерен, не согласен* и др. (потому что они либо не имеют полной формы, либо имеют в ней иное значение).

Таким образом, чтобы понять, как писать *не* с прилагательными, необходимо определить, чем оно является: **отрицательной частицей или приставкой**. Помните, что **отрицательная частица не создает нового слова**, тогда как **приставка это делает**, ср.: *Не красивый, а уродливый ковер* (отрицается слово *красивый*) и *Неправильный поступок* (слово *правильный* не отрицается; с помощью приставки *не* образовалось **новое слово**, обратное исходному).